How to manage changes in the configuration files of a python project
I have the following folder structure in my python project:
main_folder/
|-- python_code_subfolder/
|   |-- .git
|   |-- .venv
|   |-- tests/
|       |-- test_code.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- code.py 
|-- config.json
|-- headers.json
|-- body.json

The folder "python_code_subfolder" contains all my python code and it is already connected to a my git repository. The "config.json", "headers.json" and "body.json" are configuration files to manage some values in my code.py.
I did not include the previous files on my folder "python_code_subfolder" because when there is a change in those files, I am not changing my code theoritically and it would not make sense to push my code entire code and build it again because some changes in the configuration files. My first though was to create a different git repository with only those configuration files and I can only push changes to that repository without building or realising again a new version in my code.
My main question is where should I place those configuration files based on best practices and how should I manage only changes in the configuration files?. Is it a good idea to create a new repository for only my configuration files?

The git repo is inside python_code_subfolder. If you need files and folders above it to be under version control, consider moving the git repo

@evolutionxbox Just to clarify my requirement. The git repository for the python_code_subfolder contains a Azure pipeline. When there is a change in that repository I will deploy in the respective environment. If I put all together with the configuration files, then a change in the configuration file must not execute this pipeline because the code does not change. I am wondering how to achieve it based on the best practices.

"based on the best practices" whose best practices?

@evolutionxbox best practices to manage changes in configuration files when working in a python project.
